# Bind events to timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript

here is my question:

I've a website that works only during the night (after 21:00 until 24:00)
I have a button that says "Enter", but i want that button to `alert()` a message such as `'The website is not available yet'`.

But to do so it must check the time so in pseudocode:

```
    if (time is less more than 21:00 and less than 24:00) {
     return true;
    } else {
      alert('the website is not available yet');
      e.preventDefault;
      return false;
    }
```

But I don't understand how I can do that in terms time difference, in **any** day,
any hint?

thank you guys!

Comment: 21:00 UTC, a specific time zone, or what?  Also, note that 00:00 is less than 21:00, what happens at midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Date().getHours()
```

will return current hour (`13` when I am writing this at 13:42). However this solution has several drawbacks:

- it uses system time, changing the time in the computer will fool your script
- it uses system time zone, consider `getUTCHours()`
- it can be easily bypassed by disabling JavaScript or modifying the script on the fly

Thus consider fetching time from the server when rendering the page **and** repeating the test on the server side when user enters (to make sure the check was not bypassed).

Comment: this is actually interesting, i have to edit the post. In facts the website works from 21 to 24, how can i check that is that time

Comment: thanks for the limitations, the website is internal, then no problem for that :) no hackers